# Vulnerable JavaScript libraries jquery-1.7.1.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, sencha-touch

We are using jquery-1.7.1.js in Sencha Touch 2.3 , Recently we got an alert from play store i.e **Vulnerable JavaScript libraries**

Please check the bellow alert from **Play store** :

**Vulnerable JavaScript libraries:**

Name    Version Known issues    Identified files
jquery  1.7.1   SNYK-npm:jquery:20110606
SNYK-npm:jquery:20150627
SNYK-JS-JQUERY-174006   assets/www/js/jquery-1.7.1.js
3.1.0   SNYK-JS-JQUERY-174006   assets/www/js/jquery.min.js

**Let me know any further things to fix this issue and thank you in advance .**

Comment: step 1: upgrade jquery (the one you're using is 8 years old)

Comment: please let me know which version should i take , if i take new version it will effect existing code.

Comment: yes, it will - as for which version? I would recommend one that doesn't have the vulnerability - there's a 1.7.2 - that shouldn't break anything ... really, any 1.x series (1.12.?? being the latest I believe) shouldn't break your code

Comment: Afaik the XSS vulnerability  has been fixed in jQuery >= 3.1

Comment: please share the link,

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest JS Library which is 3.6.2 as of now to avoid any security issues.

https://security.snyk.io/package/npm/jquery